# Microweber multi site not working [Domain DNS Problem]

Tags: php, multisite

I want to use microweber and multisite but I have few problems.
I installed microweber and it works.

Docs;
http://docs.microweber.com/guides/installation.md

I also did the multisite setup as shown in the Microweber documentation;
https://github.com/microweber/microweber-docs/blob/master/integration/multisite.md

However, when I open my site, the microweber setup screen does not appear.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3Gi3.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/siDDB.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZGbA.png)

Multi site domain: altinkolye.net

google domains;
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vK24.png)

How should I configure Google domains A DNS? When NS redirects, it runs the index.html file in the domain.

Answer (score 0):

You must make alias domain in Plesk that can resolve both domains to the same folder.

Check here how to make alias domain https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/customer-guide/websites-and-domains/domains-and-dns/adding-domain-aliases.65286/